# Changing button states in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The program I'm working on allows the user to enter a text and check if it is a palindrome. The input is ordered with order(), tested with testPalindrome(orderedText) and then the result is shown with showResult(Palindrome). My problem arises when it comes to saving a palindrome. The user is supposed to be able to save an input if it has been verified to be a palindrome. I thought it would make sense if the save button is disabled until an input has been tested true. So I put "saveButton.config(state = 'normal')" in showResult(Palindrome), but that doesn't work. The error says "global name 'saveButton' is not defined", and I can see why. However, I can't manage to get it right. I wonder if it is possible to solve this problem with some addition to this single line of text or if I have to make more thorough modifications. (I tried for instance to turn "saveButton" into a global variable such as "inputEntry" but for whatever reason I couldn't get that to work either.)

```
    import Tkinter

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text = 'Enter a text and check if it is a palindrome.', height = 12, width = 64, bg = 'green')
    inputEntry = Tkinter.Entry(root, width = 64)

    def main():
        window()
        Tkinter.mainloop()

    def window():
        root.title('Palindrome detector')
        root.geometry('534x285+500+250')
        infoLabel.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 8, padx = 8)
        inputEntry.insert(0, 'Enter text...')
        inputEntry.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 4)
        verifyButton = Tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Verify', width = 7, command = order).grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 10)
        saveButton = Tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Save', state = 'disabled', width = 7, command = save).grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    def order():
        Text_input = inputEntry.get()
        orderedText = Text_input.replace(" ", "")
        orderedText = orderedText.lower()
        orderedText = filter(str.isalnum, orderedText)
        if any(char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() for char in orderedText):
            testPalindrome(orderedText)
        else:
            infoLabel.config(text = 'The input must contain at least one alphanumeric character.', bg = 'red')

    def testPalindrome(orderedText):
        Palindrome = True
        i = 0
        for char in orderedText:
            if orderedText[i] == orderedText[-(i+1)]:
                Palindrome = True
                i += 1
            else:
                Palindrome = False
                break
        showResult(Palindrome)

    def showResult(Palindrome):
        if Palindrome == True:
            infoLabel.config(text = 'Yes! "' + str(inputEntry.get()) + '" is a palindrome!', bg = 'green')
            saveButton.config(state = 'normal')
        else:
            infoLabel.config(text = 'No! "' + str(inputEntry.get()) + '" is not a palindrome!', bg = 'red')
            saveButton.config(state = 'disabled')

    def save():
        savePalindrome = inputEntry.get()
        palindromes_file = open("Palindromes.txt", "a")
        palindromes_file.write(savePalindrome + "\n")
        palindromes_file.close()
        infoLabel.config(text = '"' + str(savePalindrome) + '" has been saved to file.', bg = 'green')
        saveButton.config(state = 'disabled')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Edit: After reading the answers I followed a textbook and tried to rewrite the whole thing using class. Surely there may be any number of defects as a result. My concern right now is "NameError: global name 'testPalindrome' is not defined". The error regards line 7 in order(self). I can't see why this line and the "bridge" between order(self) and testPalindrome(self) suddenly is a problem?

```
    import Tkinter
    import tkMessageBox

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    class MyGUI:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            master.title('Palindrome detector')
            master.geometry('534x285+500+250')
            self.infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(self.master, text = 'Enter a text and check if it is a palindrome.', height = 12, width = 64, bg = 'green')
            self.inputEntry = Tkinter.Entry(self.master, width = 64)
            self.infoLabel.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 8, padx = 8)
            self.inputEntry.insert(0, 'Enter text...')
            self.inputEntry.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 4)
            self.verifyButton = Tkinter.Button(self.master, text = 'Verify', width = 7, command = self.order)
            self.verifyButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 10)
            self.saveButton = Tkinter.Button(self.master, text = 'Save', state = 'disabled', width = 7, command = self.save)
            self.saveButton.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        def order(self):
            self.Text_input = self.inputEntry.get()
            self.orderedText = self.Text_input.replace(" ", "")
            self.orderedText = self.orderedText.lower()
            self.orderedText = filter(str.isalnum, self.orderedText)
            if any(char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() for char in self.orderedText):
                testPalindrome(self)
            else:
                self.infoLabel.config(text = 'The input must contain at least one alphanumeric character.', bg = 'red')

        def testPalindrome(self):
            self.Palindrome = True
            i = 0
            for char in self.orderedText:
                if self.orderedText[i] == self.orderedText[-(i+1)]:
                    self.Palindrome = True
                    i += 1
                else:
                    self.Palindrome = False
                    break
            showResult(self)

        def showResult(self):
            if self.Palindrome == True:
                self.infoLabel.config(text = 'Yes! "' + str(self.inputEntry.get()) + '" is a palindrome!', bg = 'green')
                self.saveButton.config(state = 'normal')
            else:
                self.infoLabel.config(text = 'No! "' + str(self.inputEntry.get()) + '" is not a palindrome!', bg = 'red')
                self.saveButton.config(state = 'disabled')

        def save(self):
            self.savePalindrome = self.inputEntry.get()
            self.palindromes_file = open("Palindromes.txt", "a")
            self.palindromes_file.write(self.savePalindrome + "\n")
            self.palindromes_file.close()
            self.infoLabel.config(text = '"' + str(self.savePalindrome) + '" has been saved to file.', bg = 'green')
            self.saveButton.config(state = 'disabled')

    my_gui = MyGUI(root)
    Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't completely answer your question, but you should not `grid` or `pack` or `place` a widget and assign it to a variable on the same line. See [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute get](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/953482) for more information.

Comment: btw: always put full error message instead of describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `saveButton` in function so it is local variable and it is not avaliable in other functions. You can use `global saveButton` in `window()` to make this variable global.

```
def window():
    global saveButton

    # ....

    saveButton = Tkinter.Button(...)
    saveButton.grid(...)
```

--

As Kevin already said:

This line

```
 saveButton = Tkinter.Button(...).grid(...)
```

assigns `None` to `saveButton` because `grid()` always returns `None`

Use

```
 saveButton = Tkinter.Button(...)
 saveButton.grid(...)
```

or

```
 Tkinter.Button(...).grid(...)
```

if you don't need `saveButton` variable.

Comment: That "global saveButton" worked, but I thought global variables were a bit frowned upon? Are there any other methods I could investigate?

Comment: you can use Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and create class with all functions and use `self.` instead of `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the call in your verify function,since you want to automatically save every time when it is a Palindrome.  And you can pass the value to the function instead of getting it a second time.

```
def testPalindrome(orderedText):
    ## change to False so an empty string will not 
    ## register as True
    Palindrome = False
    i = 0
    for char in orderedText:
        if orderedText[i] == orderedText[-(i+1)]:
            Palindrome = True
            i += 1
        else:
            Palindrome = False
            break
    showResult(Palindrome)
    if Palindrome:
        save(orderedText)
```

Next learn classes as it solves these problems. One of many tutorials on the web http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html To make the button global, put it in the global namespace (like inputEntry).

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text = 'Enter a text and check if it is a palindrome.', height = 12, width = 64, bg = 'green')
inputEntry = Tkinter.Entry(root, width = 64)

saveButton = Tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Save', state = 'disabled', width = 7, command = save)
saveButton.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
```

Comment: Making the saveButton global in that way gives me "NameError: name 'save' is not defined".

Comment: The function has to be declared before it is used, so solving the problem is something you can figure out if you try different things.  Once again, for future attempts, a class structure does not have these kinds of problems, so most people are ignoring this thread because you are creating your own, needless problems.